# Replace values after a clone in jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, clone

I need to `clone()` a  and change the id values after.

So here's my code:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  var newRow = $('.accordion').eq(0).clone();
  var newRow = newRow.html().replace('item1', 'item2')
  $('#list-items').append(newRow);
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div id="add">Add row</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="list-items">
    <div class="panel-group accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href="ui-tabs.html#item1">Item number 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="item1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Problem is after that:
This `href="ui-tabs.html#item1"` change to `href="ui-tabs.html#item2"` but not the occurrence after. So `id="item1"` isn't change to `id="item2"`.

Any help on it ?

Comment: Can you show some HTML too?

Comment: Everything in your code works correctly in a jsfiddle. Only the text you see doesn't.

Comment: @teamo - have you checked all the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from

```
var newRow = newRow.html().replace('item1', 'item2')
```

to

```
newRow = newRow.html().replace(/item1/g, "item2");
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/4TK40ctShe585IjbVd1i?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked the code of HTML too,try this out.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newRow = $('.accordion').eq(0).clone();
    $('#list-items').append(newRow);
    $('#list-items span:last-child').attr("id",'item2');    //THIS ID SHOULD BE A DYNAMICALLY GENERATED THING.
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="add">Add row</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="list-items">
    <div class="panel-group accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="item1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <span>  ...</span>  //ADDED A SPAN
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You had a typo ... Try this:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newRow = $('.accordion').eq(0).clone();
    newRow = newRow.html().replace('item1', 'item2');
    $('#list-items').append(newRow);
});
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as his function.

Comment: Not the same ... typo is fixed!

Comment: That typo does not fix his problem.